# unhandled promise rejection when running whatsapp bot

Tags: node.js, whatsapp, unhandled-promise-rejection

I'm running a whatsapp bot and everything works fine until I get a message

```
at /root/bot/node_modules/@adiwajshing/baileys/lib/Utils/generics.js:157:32
(node:26706)
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 21)
```

I tried to search for some answers on the ChatGPT bot but that's not working, maybe someone can help me to fix this issue.
Here is the code

```
    // Create a promise that rejects in <ms> milliseconds
    const { delay, cancel } = (0, exports.delayCancellable)(ms);
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        delay
            .then(() => reject(new boom_1.Boom('Timed Out', {
            statusCode: Types_1.DisconnectReason.timedOut,
            data: {
                stack
            }
        })))
            .catch(err => reject(err));
        promise(resolve, reject);
    })
        .finally(cancel);
    return p;
}
```

Note: code at

```
root/bot/node_modules/@adiwajshing/baileys/lib/Utils/generics.js:157
```

is

```
.then(() => reject(new boom_1.Boom('Timed Out', {
```

Comment: Please be aware that the usage of ChatGPT to generate content in posts on Stack Overflow [is currently banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). That applies both to copy-pasting from ChatGPT into answers, *and also* asking questions about code generated by ChatGPT. Since ChatGPT is optimized for generating coherent human-like speech (as it is a chat bot), it does not know how to write code and produces only low-quality output. Trying to fix/improve such code is therefore futile.

Comment: I'm not using ChatGPT to generate content, I'm just searching for an answer but don't find anything because I'm hew here

Comment: `.catch(err => reject(err))` is totally redundant